# A generic error occured in GDI+

Tags: windows, winforms, active-directory, gdi+

I have a legacy Winforms app that, when using it is causing some strange problems. Portions of the app deal with images, users can add images to a record and those images are resized in .Net and saved to a server share. I'm having two problems using this application that both result in "A generic error occured in GDI+".

Users can view the record and the images show up fine, they can try to print and the dialog to choose a printer comes up, but when they click print, they get the error. The other is when users try to add a new image to a record, same generic error. The best part - only two users have this problem.

The images can be opened up from the share directly and printed, no problem. Both users are part of the same AD group with permissions on the share/files as everyone else. Both users logging into the app on another machine and doing the same works fine. I've tried giving the two individuals full control and ownership on the shared files, but still the same error. Uninstalling and reinstalling the app has no effect.

I've logged into each affected users machine and the application is installed on a per-user basis, but installing and running the app on the same machine with my credentials runs fine.

Anyone have advice from previous experience with this problem, or what I should try next?

Edit: This all started when we moved the shared folder to another server.

Comment: GDI+ exceptions are pretty lousy, but this is almost always a permission problem.  Make 100% that you know exactly *where* the file is being written and that the user has appropriate rights to the server share.  And that the file they are trying to write to might not be locked by another machine on the network.

Answer (score 2):

There is an old bug in .NET 2.0. However this bug happens only under Terminal Server or in Remote Desktop/Assistance session.

More info and workaround:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953389

**Update Jan 2017.** Microsoft have deleted the KB953389 article. It is still in the cached by some search engines.

Here is what is says:

**Action**

You are running a Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Windows Forms application in a Terminal Server session. You then minimize the termial server session window, disconnect from the session, or lock the session.
Result

When resuming work in the terminal server session, the Windows Forms application displays the following exception and call stack:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+.
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.Clear(Color color)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripProfessionalRenderer.OnRenderToolStripContentPanelBackground(ToolStripContentPanelRenderEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripProfessionalRenderer.OnRenderToolStripContentPanelBackground(ToolStripContentPanelRenderEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripRenderer.DrawToolStripContentPanelBackground(ToolStripContentPanelRenderEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripContentPanel.OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer, Boolean disposeEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmEraseBkgnd(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

**Cause**

This is due to a bug in the Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0. The Windows Forms run-time is attempting to call System.Drawing.Graphics.Clear without checking to see if it is running on a secure desktop. As documented in the following MSDN link, if the Clear method is called on a secure desktop in a terminal server session, an ExternalException may occur, leaving the Graphics object in an inconsistent state.

**Graphics.Clear Method**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.clear.aspx

**Resolution**

You can work around this behavior by wiring an event handler to the Application.ThreadException event. This event allows your application code to handle otherwise unhandled exceptions that occur in Windows Forms threads. This would allow your code to be called instead of the standard Windows Forms exception dialog being displayed.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   AddHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf Application_ThreadException
End Sub

Sub Application_ThreadException(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs)

   If TypeOf (e.Exception) Is System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException Then
      Return
   End If
   MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message, Me.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: B, well the link is broken, ill keep the point, however can you find the new article and fix the link?

Atleast this is a lead for me, tells me its a .NET issue,  Not sure whats causing it.  I just want it gone.

Answer (score 0):

You could try several things:

1. When you open the image from the share, clone it in memory (create a new `Bitmap` object and copy all of the contents from the original image) and continue working with that in-memory object.
2. ... or physically copy the image file from the share to the user's computer before opening it for printing.

Comment: This assumes I have the ability to edit the application. Regardless, the application works fine as is for all other users, so I don't think a code change is appropriate here. Thanks though.

Comment: sorry no point for you, my issue is totally not related, im just getting this error straight on my desktop, its bugging the hell out of me.